# whats the difference between something.somethingElse and something->somethingElse

Tags: objective-c, syntax

In objective-c whats the difference between using a . and using ->? I've used dot notation many times but have only just come across ->

E.G

```
Object.subObject

or

Object->subObject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `myObject.myProperty`

The dot could either be calling a the getter/setter for a property or accessing a struct.

In your case subObject is probably not a struct so using `myObject.myProperty` would be the same as calling the method `[myObject myProperty]` which is the getter for the "myProperty" property.

The same way when you are setting a new value using the dot. You are calling `[myObject setMyProperty:newValue];` which will do the appropriate memory management defined for your property (like retain, copy or assign the value as well as release the old value).

(Using getters and setters will also call the work with KVO)

---

### `myObject->myProperty`

The arrow is pointing to the memory of the variable.

This simply means that you are following the pointer that points to the memory where `myProperty` is located. This is lower level and does not do any memory management for you, nor does it work with KVO.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I still don't quite understand why you would use -> surly using the getter and setter is the correct way to access your variables?

Comment: Yes, you get a lot for free when using properties. There are a few cases where you might want to go straight to the memory of the other object but unless you know that it is one of those cases, it probably isn't.